# Whatsapp send text message url scheme equivalent

Tags: url-scheme, wechat

When I need to send text message via Whatsapp in a web page, I can use the following url scheme.

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=hello%20world">send</a>
```

I want to achieve the same effect using Wechat and QQ. I know the their url scheme start with `weixin://` and `mqq://`. I successfully open the respective app but fail to find a way to send text message. How can I do that?